# Gutenberg: Heading with subheading/paragraph

Tags: block-editor

How can this be modeled with existing blocks or other means?

I want a heading block and a paragraph block visually (and semantically, if possible and necessary) grouped together.

Example:
Circle around the heading block with text "Hairstyle" and a paragraph block below with text "Beautify your hair".

I can use a group block with a heading block and a paragraph block inside - but I find this quite cumbersome and complex. Can I at least make this group-heading-paragraph block structure reusable and lock it somehow so that only the text and its position as a whole can be changed by the editor user?

Comment: this sounds like a block pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it seems a [block pattern](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-patterns/) might suffice. The Group block has a `templateLock` attribute which can be set to `all` to prevent any additional blocks from being inserted within and also keep the Heading and Paragraph blocks from being moved or deleted.

Here's an example with the template lock and a custom class added to the Group block.

```php
add_action( 'init', function(){
    register_block_pattern(
        'my-plugin/dually-heading',
        [
            'title'       => __( 'Heading with sub-heading', 'my-plugin' ),
            'categories'  => [ 'header' ],
            'content'     => <<<MARKUP
                <!-- wp:group {"templateLock":"all"} -->
                <div class="wp-block-group dually-heading">
                    <!-- wp:heading --><h2>Get some at HUD</h2><!-- /wp:heading -->
                    <!-- wp:paragraph --><p>The candy store of covert revenues</p><!-- /wp:paragraph -->
                </div>
                <!-- /wp:group -->
            MARKUP
        ]
    );
} );
```

Comment: Can the newly introduced `patterns` property in `theme.json` be used for this? Or can it only be used to reference to block patterns in the official WordPress patterns directory?